# How to Find UID, GID, and any groups I belong to?

Tags: linux, command-line, users, group

How to Find UID, GID, and any groups I belong to ?

Comment: You can use [id](http://linux.die.net/man/1/id).

Answer (score 10):

The command that you must use for you is:

```
id
```

and for any other user:

```
id username
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a list containing all group membership use `id -a`